# Making a 'quiz' - how do I show previous answer?

Tags: php, while-loop

I'm making a sort of 'quiz'. The user gets asked a question and can choose between three answers. Here is my code:

```
// query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `db_game` LEFT JOIN `db_game_printers` ON (db_game.printerId = db_game_printers.id) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

// explode answers
$row['printerQuestion'] = trim($row['printerQuestion']);
$question = explode(",", $row['printerQuestion']);

$printerQuestion = $row['title'];
$printerAnswer = $row['printerAnswer'];

// check answer
$answer = $row['printerAnswer'];
    if (isset($_GET['answer'])) {
        $answerUser = $_GET['answer'];
        if ($answerUser == $answer) {
            $correct = true;
        } else {
            $false = true;
        }
    }
```

It works as expected. When the user answers the question by clicking on the answer the next question is shown. I would also like to show if they actually answered correct, or incorrect! I wrote this code:

```
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="question">
<h1><?= $printerQuestion; ?></h1>
</div><!-- /question -->

<ul id="answers">
    <li style="text-align:left;"><a href="index.php?answer=<?=$question[0];?>"><button class="punch"><?=$question[0];?></button></a></li>
    <li style="text-align:center;"><a href="index.php?answer=<?=$question[1];?>"><button class="punch"><?=$question[1];?></button></a></li>
    <li style="text-align:right;"><a href="index.php?answer=<?=$question[2];?>"><button class="punch"><?=$question[2];?></button></a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear" style="margin-bottom:50px;"></div>


<?php
$prev_printerQuestion = $printerQuestion;
$prev_printerAnswer = $printerAnswer;

} // end while loop
?>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['answer'])) {
    if ($correct) {
        echo "Correct! The ".$prev_printerQuestion." uses the ".$prev_printerAnswer."";
    }
    else if ($false) {
        echo "Not correct. ".$prev_printerQuestion." = ".$prev_printerAnswer."" ;
    }
}
?>

</div><!-- /wrapper -->
```

The check to see if the answer is correct uses the current data. Not from the previous question. I tried placing the values in a seperate variable and outside (and inside) the while loop, but it made no difference.

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: Can you just show us all the code in one block. It matters which order these snippets are in the file.

Answer (score 2):

First, define some functions to represent what you are trying to do in the application.  (I'm going to stop with functions here and not talk about OO principles, to keep it simple).

Understanding this *encapsulation* of your application's functionality is a first step to good software design.

In your case, your view layer is quite simple:

```
function displayQuestion($question, $answers) { /* display html for question and possible answers */ }
```

In order to display the question, you need to get the question and its answers from the database.  You might do this:

```
function getQuestion($questionNumber) { /* performs SQL queries and returns some representation of question, answers and correct answer */ }
```

Then you have the real "business" (game) logic itself, which is:

```
function checkAnswer($questionNumber, $answerGiven) { /* returns true or false */ }
```

You also need some functions to control the game as a whole, maybe like:

```
function startNewGame() { /* reset internal variables */ }

function getCurrentQuestionNumber() { /* get the question that the user is up to */ }

function displayCurrentScore() { /* display html for current score */ }
```

The final part is to wire it all together.  (I mean final in the discussion, not the last thing you do).  This is where you connect the parts together, starting from the HTTP request, through to the model and business logic, and back to the view layer to display the pages to the user via the HTTP response.  You can conceivable encapsulate this whole process as a method:

```
function handleRequest() { /* perform the whole request-response cycle, calling the other methods as required */ }
```

Note that the above is just a broad and pretty generalised approach to these functions and what they do, I don't know your exact requirements so there will be parts missing.  It is also not quite "best practice" but it is better than mixing your business logic and database access into your HTML code :-)